# Improve performance of a For Loop in R to calculate all Shapley values

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization

I am currently working on a For loop in R. If I run the For loop on my own data, it takes ages, and I believe because I did something inefficient in my code. Could you please help me with improving it?

```
# Loop through the samples, explaining one instance at a time.
shap_values <- vector("list", nrow(X))  # initialize the results list.
system.time({
  for (i in seq_along(shap_values)) {
    set.seed(224)
    shap_values[[i]] <- iml::Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = X[i, ],sample.size = 30)$results
    shap_values[[i]]$predicted_value <- iml::Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = X[i, ],sample.size = 30)$y.hat.interest
    shap_values[[i]]$sample_num <- i  # identifier to track our instances.
  }
  data_shap_values <- dplyr::bind_rows(shap_values)  # collapse the list.
})
```

I believe that my problem is in the

```
shap_values[[i]]$sample_num
```

variable, since I am redoing there the calculations of the previous

```
shap_values[[i]]$predicted_value
```

variable. The reason why I added that variable, was because I needed the

```
$y.hat.interest
```

as part of the new data frame (which is called "shap_values" and later "data_shap_values").

**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE: (starts at "This is the important part:)**

```
#Example Shapley
#https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iml/vignettes/intro.html

data("Boston", package  = "MASS")
head(Boston)

set.seed(42)
#install.packages("iml")
library("iml")
library("randomForest")
data("Boston", package  = "MASS")
rf = randomForest(medv ~ ., data = Boston, ntree = 50)

# We create a Predictor object, that holds the model and the data. 
# The iml package uses R6 classes: New objects can be created by calling Predictor$new()
X = Boston[which(names(Boston) != "medv")]
predictor = Predictor$new(rf, data = X, y = Boston$medv)

# Feature Importance
## Shifting each future, and measring how much the performance drops ## 
imp = FeatureImp$new(predictor, loss = "mae")
plot(imp)


# Shapley value. Assume that for 1 data point, the feature values play a game together, in which 
# they get the prediction as payout. Tells us how fairly distibute the payout among the feature values. 
View(X)
shapley = Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = X[1,])
shapley$plot()

# Reuse the object to explain other data points 
shapley$explain(x.interest = X[2,])
shapley$plot()

# Results in data.frame form can be extracted like this: 
results = shapley$results
head(results)


# THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART: 

# It might make sense for testing, to reduce the data: 
X = X[1:10,]

# Loop through the samples, explaining one instance at a time.
shap_values <- vector("list", nrow(X))  # initialize the results list.
system.time({
  for (i in seq_along(shap_values)) {
    set.seed(224)
    shap_values[[i]] <- iml::Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = X[i, ],sample.size = 30)$results
    shap_values[[i]]$predicted_value <- iml::Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = X[i, ],sample.size = 30)$y.hat.interest
    shap_values[[i]]$sample_num <- i  # identifier to track our instances.
  }
  data_shap_values <- dplyr::bind_rows(shap_values)  # collapse the list.
})
```

**Update**

As requested by @Ralf Stubner a Profiling of the for loop:

[image]

Comment: Have you profiled your code to identify the bottlenecks?

Comment: Hi Ralf, thanks for your reply. No I didn't, I am not aware how I can do that

Comment: See https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/05/23/profiling-with-rstudio-and-profvis/ for a simple method integrated into RStudio (c.f. "Profile" menu).

Comment: Thanks have updated my answer. But I am still stuck in how to make it faster, unless the new insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doubling your run-time by calling `imp::Shapely$new` twice with identical parameters. As an alternative, you can create the object once and extract the two values:

```
system.time({
    for (i in seq_along(shap_values)) {
        set.seed(224)
        shapley <- iml::Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = X[i, ],sample.size = 30)
        shap_values[[i]] <- shapley$results
        shap_values[[i]]$predicted_value <- shapley$y.hat.interest
        shap_values[[i]]$sample_num <- i  # identifier to track our instances.
    }
    data_shap_values <- dplyr::bind_rows(shap_values)  # collapse the list.
})
```

If you have sufficient RAM to store your data multiple times, you might also try parallel processing using `parallel`, `foreach` or `future.apply`.

Comment: It saved indeed almost 50% of the running time on my computer (ran it 'normal' without Parallel computing). Appreciated Ralf!!